# Как сохранить сессию AR core с возможностью восстановления?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ar, arcore

коллеги! 
Стоит такая задача - в уже написанном приложении с помощью AR core реализована возможность расстановки 3д моделек, необходимо сохранить стейт сцены, чтобы при повторном запуске приложения все объекты сцены восстанавливались. Сейчас же приходиться расставлять всё заново. Приложение всегда используется исключительно в одном помещении.

Answer (score 0):

ArCore не допускает сохранения сессии, но частично это можно решить путём работы с Cloud Anchors.

Точно не помню где я встречал обсуждение, но гуглы мотивировали это тем, что устройство однозначно перемещалось пока отслеживание было не активно, и поэтому нужно получить координатную привязку заново.

Comment: То есть, как я понял, прямого решения с реализацией моей задачи нету?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему можно решить с помощью [Cloud Anchors API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android), правда там есть ограничение - данные хранятся пока что только 24 часа.